# обновить таблицы в базе doctrine symfony 3

Tags: symfony, symfony3, sonata

Всем привет. Изучаю Symfony 3 в связке с sonata-admin-bundle, дошел до момента когда нужно загружать файлы (изображения), установил sonata MediaBundle, НО ! дошел до пункта когда нужно обновить базу через doctrine:schema:update, и тут застрял... при попытке обновить таблицы получаю ошибку

> **The table with name 'symfony.articles' already exists.**

перегуглил все что только можно было, везде все упираются в зависимости OneToMany и т.д. в общем что только не делал - даже удалял во всех сущностях зависимости - все равно получаю ту же ошибку. Я понимаю, что где то есть файлик с построенными связями, но как это все побороть? Я конечно могу все убить и все создать сначала и только потом запустить обновление базы, но это же не выход! Ведь потом буду дальше подключать бандлы и опять вылезет та же ошибка. Подскажите , пожалуйста решение.

Comment: Я пологая ошибка возникает потому что ты пытаешься создать 2 таблицу article или повторно её создать когда она уже есть . Если ты все же полагаешь что ошибка именно в не корректных связях то запусти команду  doctrine:schema:validate это команда покажет ошибки текущей схемы и связей.

Comment: @ВадимБондаренко       таблица article уже существует, это да, но как мне тогда добавлять еще таблицы? ведь мне нужно обновить базу после установки бандла

Comment: У меня такое ощущения, что у вас 2 сущности с одинаковым названием таблицы. Ошибка понятная. При выполнении команды доктрина пытается создать 2 раза таблицу . Вы команду выполняли что я писал. Ошибки были ?

Comment: @ВадимБондаренко да, Maping OK и потом пишет что таблица уже есть

Comment: ура! нашел! да, действительно в аннотации в другой сущности было обьявление такой же таблицы! спасибо вам большое!

Comment: отметь мой ответ. Он был верный .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка говорит нам о том что doctrine пытается 2 раза создать таблицу articles. Подобное поведение может быть вызвано тем что вы объявили эту таблицу в 2-х сущностях. Одну из них надо переименовать.